# Hide "Created By" from Flow Approval e-mail

Tags: workflow, power-automate

When the Flow Approval is generated, an automatic email sent to approver contains two variables: Requested for and Created By.
Requested for is a person that requires the approval.
Created by is a person that designed the flow and this variable should be hidden (not visible to the approver). Is there any possibility to achieve that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Requested for" field in the email is mapped to the "Requestor" field in the Approval action. It can be edited but it cannot be empty.

I cannot find the source for the "Created by" field in the email. Initially I thought it was the owner of the Approval connection, but that is not the case.

I know this is a partial answer, but I thought it might save you some effort.

Comment: In case it helps, the "Created by" depends on whoever created the workflow. What I ended up doing (since I was the original creator) was to export the flow as a .zip, disable it, and re-import it as a "system-like" user (i.e. one we use to run flows). 
Still shows the "Created by" in the email template, but at least now is not a regular user.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Field "From (send as)" in the "show advanced options" of the email (V2). This will render the "created by" flow message unnecessary.